# Why the keyboard input is written back to IO bus in xv6?

Tags: unix, operating-system, xv6

I do not understand why the input got from keyboard interrupt is written back to the io bus again:

This is the keyboard interrupt handler:

```
void consoleintr(int (*getc)(void)) {
    // I skipped some code for simplicity

    default:
      if(c != 0 && input.e-input.r < INPUT_BUF){
        c = (c == '\r') ? '\n' : c;

        input.buf[input.e++ % INPUT_BUF] = c;
----->  consputc(c);

        if(c == '\n' || c == C('D') || input.e == input.r+INPUT_BUF){
          input.w = input.e;
          wakeup(&input.r);
        }
      }

      break;
    }
  }
```

The input `c` is taken from `getc` function and written to `input.buf` ring buffer and right after that it is passed to `consputc` function.

`consputc` function calls `uartputc` which calls `outb(COM1+0, c)`.

The `uartgetc` function also registered as a input for `consoleintr` function:

```
static int uartgetc(void) {
    if (!uart) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (!(inb(COM1 + 5) & 0x01)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return inb(COM1+0);
}

void uartintr(void) {
    consoleintr(uartgetc);
}
```

Links to the code:

1. consoleintr: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/console.c#L192
2. consputc: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/console.c#L166
3. uartputc: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/uart.c#L52

Answer (score 2):

The key pressed from keyboard is not resent to be processed again, but is send to output:

The uart is some kind of serial line, it is used in two ways: input and output.

The keyboard in only an input device.

When you press a key, the key pressed will be sent to serial out.

A small schematics may explain better:

```
+-------------+                                   
|             |                                   +--------------+
| Keyboard    +-----+                       +---->+ Screen (term)|
|             |     |                       |     +--------------+
+-------------+     |    +------------+     |     
                    |    |            |     |      +----------------+
                    +--->| Char to    +-----+----->+ Input (process)|----> ....
                    |    |   process  |     |      +----------------+   
+--------------+    |    +------------+     |     +--------------+
|              |    |                       +---->+ Serial: out  |
| Serial: in   +----+                             |  outb(...)   |
|  inb(...)    |                                  +--------------+
+--------------+
```

Comment: Mathieu, why it is needed to send a key pressed from keyboard to serial output? Isn't it enough to save it in the buffer and just send it to the screen?

Comment: Is my assumption true that char passed from keyboard can be later used by other software  and consoleintr is just one of them ?

Comment: @maksadbek the serial line implementation is used for remote access. It can be really useful for debugging purpose.